# How to kill openerp when it changes PID?

Tags: kill, ps, odoo, openerp

How do I kill `openerp` so that `odoo` can [run](https://askubuntu.com/q/1335246/847449) correctly?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ps aux | grep openerp
nicholas   75353  0.0  0.0  17528   880 pts/0    S+   18:46   0:00 grep --color=auto openerp
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ps aux | grep openerp
nicholas   75356  0.0  0.0  17528   880 pts/0    S+   18:46   0:00 grep --color=auto openerp
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ps aux | grep openerp
nicholas   75358  0.0  0.0  17528   880 pts/0    S+   18:46   0:00 grep --color=auto openerp
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsof -i :880
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ps aux | grep openerp
nicholas   75388  0.0  0.0  17528   880 pts/0    S+   18:48   0:00 grep --color=auto openerp
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ kill 17528
bash: kill: (17528) - No such process
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ kill 75388
bash: kill: (75388) - No such process
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ps aux | grep openerp
nicholas   75394  0.0  0.0  17528   816 pts/0    S+   18:49   0:00 grep --color=auto openerp
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Comment: ... those are the PIDs of your grep process

Comment: err, are you sure @steeldriver ?